# Plot nested matrix and label according to sublist

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, matrix

I have a nested matrix `xyPairsAll` that contains {x, y} pairs:

```
{...
{{{1., 1812.}, {2., 10076.}, {3., 4764}},   
 {{1., 3475.}, {2., 3572.}, {3., 3985.}}}, 
{{{1., 6839.}, {2., 3849.}, {3., 2746}},    
 {{1., 3578.}, {2., 5629.}, {3., 3849.}}}, 
{{{1., 6839.}, {2., 3849.}, {3., 2746}},    
 {{1., 10092.}, {2., 1638.}, {3., 3728.}}}
...}
```

I need to plot `xyPairsAll` with ListPlot. It would be easy if I could just flatten it to one level, but I need to keep the sublists distinct so that I can color the plot according to sublist.

The following statement only plots the first sublist:

```
ListPlot[#, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, Full},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {{1, 2, 3}, None}},
   FrameLabel -> {"Time points", "Concentrations of CO2"},
   ImageSize -> Full,
   PlotLegends -> labels] & /@ xyPairsAll
```

How can I plot `xyPairsAll` so that both conditions are met:

- each {x, y} pair gets its own dot
- all {x, y} pairs from each sublist share the same color

EDIT: In the original data matrix, I had a header plus `xyPairsAll`. I set `labels` to part of the header for the columns for the y-coordinates which each represent values of CO2 for a location (like `{"Toronto, ON", "Boston, MA", "Washington, DC"...}`), and `xyPairsAll` to all the corresponding rows after the header. So each sublist in `xyPairsAll` represents {x, y} values for a location. If I flatten the `xyPairsAll`, I don't think I can tell which {x, y} values are for which location. It'd just be one long list of {x, y} pairs.

Comment: `ListPlot@Flatten[xyPairsAll, 1]`?

Comment: I've done that, but I can't tell if it labels accurately by sublist? Since the sublists change after doing `Flatten[xyPairsAll, 1]` @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: It is not labeling accurately by sublist.

Comment: Can you edit the question and give an example how you store the `labels`? Flatten preserves the order, so usually you can use something like `(ListPlot[#[[1]],PlotLegends->#[[2]]]&)/@Transpose[{Flatten[xyPairsAll,1],Flatten[sublistlabels,1]}]`.

Comment: Edited my question. Please let me know if more information is needed.  @ThiesHeidecke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the fact the `ListPlot` you tried produces only the first "sublist", I deduced that your sublists are the first level of the list. Then this must mean that you're trying to flatten the two levels below that. This can be done with `Flatten` too:

```
l = { {{{1., 1812.}, {2., 10076.}, {3., 4764}}, {{1., 3475.}, {2., 
     3572.}, {3., 3985.}}}, {{{1.1, 6839.}, {2.1, 3849.}, {3.1, 
     2746}}, {{1.1, 3578.}, {2., 5629.}, {3., 3849.}}}, {{{1., 
     6839.}, {2., 3849.}, {3., 2746}}, {{1., 10092.}, {2., 
     1638.}, {3., 3728.}}}}

ListPlot@Flatten[l, {{1}, {2, 3}}]
```

The second argument to `Flatten` says that level `1` should stay untouched, but that the next two levels should be merged.